# How to edit a particular line based on the input I give in Unix Scripting

Tags: shell, unix

I have wrote a program in bash, where there will be details of the students in a file and on passing input as roll no to it I need to edit that particular line in the file.

But when I tried by passing the roll no, it is displaying the whole file to me for editing when condition matches.

Here is my program:

```
#!/bin/bash

input="/home/kalyan/Desktop/Exercise/studet.txt"
while IFS=":" read -r rollno name s1 s2 s3
do
echo "$rollno"
done < "$input"
read -p "Enter the Roll No:" rollno1
if [ "$rollno"-eq"$rollno1" ]; then
nano studet.txt
cat studet.txt
else
echo "Doesn't match"
fi
```

or this program

```
#!/bin/bash

file="/home/kalyan/Desktop/Exercise/"

FILE="/home/kalyan/Desktop/Exercise/studet.txt"

echo "file to be processed $FILE" 
cat $FILE
echo "Reading Roll Number:"
read -r rollno;
if grep $rollno /home/kalyan/Desktop/Exercise/studet.txt
then
echo "Roll No exists"
else
echo "Roll No doesn't exists"
fi
```

Here I'm trying to get a record of a student based on the *roll no* as input.
when the *roll no* matches I'm displaying his rollno, name, marks of three subjects(s1,s2,s3).
Now I need to edit the line which matches the criteria.

Comment: it displayed the file because you used `cat` command which show the content of a file... what and where you want to change?

Comment: Note that spacing matters a ***lot*** in shell scripting.  The line `if [ "$rollno"-eq"$rollno1" ];` needs spaces around `-eq` to stand a chance of working as expecting: `if [ "$rollno" -eq "$rollno1" ];` — As written, the test will always be true because the string `"${rollno}-eq${rollno1}"` won't be empty.  Also, when the `if` is executed, `$rollno` will always be the roll number of the last student.  You need to rethink your loop and test logic.

Comment: @KalyanA: With `nano studet.txt`, you are offering the whole file for editing. There is no way that you can control that only a certain line will be edited. To ensure that only one line is changed, split your file into three parts: The lines before, the line to be changed, and the lines after. Run the editor only with the line which can be changed, and put the pieces together afterwards. You might want to verify that after editing, it is still only a single line. Of course it is then questionable why you want to use a full-blown text editor for editing a single line....

Comment: @user1934428 : I'm not aware how to edit a single line so I used nano to check the logic is working or not.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler : Can you please now check my program (2nd one) and help me with an answer for it

Comment: `Now I need to edit the line which matches the criteria.` I already answerd that but in another way.

Comment: @AmaniBenAzzouz : I guess by "editing" the line, the OP means that the user should not be required to type in the content of the new line, but instead gets presented the existing line, and is allowed to use the cursor and editing keys to change it. At least this would explain why he used `nano` in his first approach, and this indeed would be more user friendly that requesting to type in the whole line again. Of course it would be indeed more helpful if the OP would be more precise when asking for help.

Comment: @KaylanA : In order to let the user edit a single line, you shouldn't do this in a Posix shell, as you requested; at least I'm not aware that this would work in a Posix shell. If you, for instance, let your script run under *bash*, you could do a `read -i "$old_line" -e new_line`. This would present to the user the content of the variable *old_line* for editing, and the edited content would then be stored in the shell variable *new_line*. See the bash man page for details.

Comment: You've not yet shown how you want to edit the line — or, rather, you show using the `nano` editor on the file to edit the line, and any others in the file.  Don't underestimate the utility of that approach, but it isn't exactly scriptable.  Once you've identified the roll number to be edited, how do you define what the new record should look like?  Are you going to take command line arguments: `edit_studet 45 'Mickey Mouse' 34 21 91` to set the record for roll number 45?  Are you going to allow specifying some of the fields to be edited?  What gives?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure I understand fully what you are doing, but I would do (based on title of the question):

```
line_number=`grep -n "^$rollno\$" /tmp/a | cut -d : -f 1 "$input"`
nano +"$line_number" studet.txt
```

Is this last file the same as `$input`?

Comment: Here I'm trying edit the particular details of a student taking *roll no* as input. I have used *nano* to check the loop is working or not and after that I have given *Cat* to know whether the edited details are as expected. But basically in this program I need to edit the particular line based on the input I give i.e., *roll no*

Comment: I have added the lines you gave to my program. It is displaying grep /tmp/a no such file or directory

Answer (score 0):

I'am not sure if this what you want to have... but say that you want to change a user name depending on its id given as input while running the program:

#### studet.txt

```
1:surname1:name1:age1
2:surname2:name2:age2
3:surname3:name3:age3
```

#### script.sh

```
#!/bin/bash
read -p "Enter the Roll No:" rollno
read -p "Enter new name:" name
awk  -F  ":" -v roll="$rollno" -v name="$name" 'BEGIN {OFS = ":"} $1==roll {$3=name}1' studet.txt > testfile.tmp && mv testfile.tmp studet.txt
```

The above script will ask the user to pass `rollno` (exp `1`) and `name` values.

Then `awk` commad will check if the given rollno exists in the file first fileds (file will be splited into fields using `:` separator), if this rollno exists the third field of the same line will be changed by the value `name` the user passed before.

Give it a try by passing `1` and then some string and then check your file.

Comment: can you please check my updated question (2nd program) and help me with an answer @Amani Ben Azzouz